# iPad Home Screen Icon Pixelated when inatlled via Ad-Hoc

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes

I am testing my app via Ad-Hoc Distribution and have run into a strange problem.

When testing via Xcode to my iOS device everything looks and works exactly as expected; however when installing the app through iTunes (using an IPA file generated in Xcode using the Ad-Hoc Provisiong Profile) the Home Screen icon appears pixelated, as if the wrong size version is being used.

Does anyone know what's going on; is this normal behavior because this is a Ad-Hoc distro?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same problem; turns out the Simulator that comes with Xcode ignores the case of a file name, while the actual iPad does not. This will lead to the incorrect home screen icon being displayed on the iPad home screen, if the case of the icon name was changed in the directory or Xcode.

I hope this helps some one!